# Car Radio stop playing when the car is in motion / moving

Tags: audio

My Car radio stop playing when the car start to move. If i play the radio when is not moving i don't exprience the stop / play what could be the problem? I took the car to the dealership and they said they cannot fine the problem is this possible.

Comment: Yes, loose connection, good luck finding it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question needs more detail.  When you say stop playing do you mean the radio loses power and turns off? Does the sound cut out completely or cut in and out as you go over bumps? Is it the actual AM/FM radio that has the problem or the CD player? What is the make, model and year of the car?